# It stops for a while when button is clicked

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-game-engine, coroutine

```
public class green : MonoBehaviour
{
    private AudioSource source;
    public AudioClip sound;
    static int result = 0;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
        Debug.Log("a");
    }

    IEnumerator RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes()
    {
        System.Random ran = new System.Random();
        int timeToWait = ran.Next(1, 50) * 1000;
        Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);

        source = this.gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        source.clip = sound;
        source.loop = true;
        source.Play();

        System.Random r = new System.Random();
        result = r.Next(1, 4);
        Debug.Log("d");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f * 60f);

        gm.life -= 1;
        Debug.Log(gm.life + "값");
        source.Stop();
        Debug.Log("z");
        if (gm.life >= 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    public void Update()
    {
        if (result == 1 && gm.checkeat == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("e");

            gm.life += 1;
            Debug.Log("j");
            Debug.Log(gm.life + "값");
            source.Stop();
            gm.checkeat = false;
            StopCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
            StartCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
        }
        if (result == 2 && gm.checkshit == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("f");

            gm.life += 1;
            Debug.Log("o");
            Debug.Log(gm.life + "값");
            source.Stop();
            gm.checkshit = false;
            StopCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
            StartCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");

        }
        else if (result == 3 && gm.checksleep == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("g");
            gm.life += 1;
            Debug.Log(gm.life);
            Debug.Log(gm.life + "값");
            source.Stop();
            gm.checksleep = false;
            StopCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
            StartCoroutine("RoutineCheckInputAfter3Minutes");
        }
    }
}
```

public class gm : MonoBehaviour
{

```
static public int life = 0;
static public bool checkeat = false;
static public bool checkshit = false;
static public bool checksleep = false;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

}

public void eating(string eat)
{

    Debug.Log(life + "값");
    checkeat = true;
}

public void shitting(string shit)
{

    Debug.Log(life + "값");
    checkshit = true;
}

public void sleeping(string sleep)
{

    Debug.Log(life + "값");
    checksleep = true;

}
```

}

when i click a button , program stops for a while and then works... i think it is because of thread or something... 
please share your opinion..
.when i click a button , program stops for a while and then works... i think it is because of thread or something... 
please share your opinion..

Comment: I think you really need to post a [mcve]. Right now you have missing code so it's hard for us to diagnose.

Comment: You say the program stops "for a while". How long, exactly is "a while"?

Comment: _It rubs the lotion on its skin or else it gets the hose again_

Comment: @Enigmativity i add the code for the button.

Comment: @ChrisF it stops for about 1minutes...and then works again.

Comment: @MickyD what is your meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop using :

```
Thread.Sleep(timeToWait);
```

This stalls the entire thread, in this case Unity completely from running.

Since your using routines anyway, use this instead :

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(timeToWait);
```

And change this line :

```
int timeToWait = ran.Next(1, 50) * 1000;
```

To this :

```
int timeToWait = ran.Next(1, 50);
```